# java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host error

Tags: java, email, connection, connection-refused

I am trying to send email from my company's outlook using Java Mail API and I am getting this connection refused error. I checked host information and credentials and they are valid. I am using 1.6.2 version of javax.mail from Maven.

Edit Update : Now I thought about it and since I am trying this from my local and I am suspecting this is because of the firewall issue. I just want some insights from people who have experienced this before and what did they do to resolve.

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Email {

@Test
public static void sendEmail(){
   Properties props = new Properties(); 
   props.put("mail.smtp.host", "SMTP.ABC.DEF.COM");
   props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
   props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
   props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

   Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, 
   new javax.mail.Authenticator() {      
   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {        
   return new PasswordAuthentication("john.doe@abc.com", "xxxx");
    }
   });

   try {

   Message message = new MimeMessage(session);                  
   message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("john.doe@abc.com"));  
   message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("john.doe@abc.com"));
   message.setSubject("testing");  
   BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
   messageBodyPart1.setText("This is message body");  
   Transport.send(message);

   } catch (MessagingException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
 }
}


java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: 
SMTP.ABC.DEF.COM, 587; timeout -1;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: Why is it wriiten twice? props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); Also please check if you need to make your account less secure to send email , as in case of gmail

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi  thank you. The double code was typo in my part I fixed it. Security is handled by different team and I am not sure if they will agree to downgrade the security level as it is enterprise email. I am just curious can they downgrade security level for specific email address?

Comment: Not sure about that. I think you enterprise will their own email server too.